# new FacebookClient() doesnt work

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have installed the Facebook C# SDK from Nuget but I can't get the code to work:

> The type or namespace name 'FacebookClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Do I need to add a reference to any certain file before I can use the C# SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to include a reference to the file that contains `FacebookClient`.
How else would the compiler know where to look for it?